# Any specific reason why i am getting nullpointer exception at line 27 and 28 respectively

Tags: java, hibernate, struts-1

Null pointer exception at object creation places
creating a c object here and passing it to registration method
getting null pointer exception

I have commented the two lines where null pointer exception arises.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.bookstore.formbeans.RegistrationActionForm;
import com.bookstore.pojo.Customer;
import com.bookstore.service.CustomerService;

public class RegistrationAction extends Action {
    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String status ="";
        RegistrationActionForm actionForm= (RegistrationActionForm) form;
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setCno(actionForm.getCno());
        c.setCname(actionForm.getCname());
        c.setCphon(actionForm.getCphon());
        c.setCaddr(actionForm.getCaddr());
        
        CustomerService cService = new CustomerService();
        //status = cService.registration(c);
        return mapping.findForward(status);
    }
}
```

```
import com.bookstore.pojo.Customer;
import com.bookstore.util.HibernateUtil;

public class CustomerService {
    public String registration(Customer c){
        String status="";
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Customer c1 = (Customer)session.get(Customer.class, c.getCno());
            if(c1 == null){
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(c);
                tx.commit();
                status="success";
            }else{
                status = "existed";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //tx.rollback();
            status = "failure";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

tried instantiating with different methods

Answer (score 0):

First commented line: Cannot possibly itself be the cause of an NPE. The actual NPE is in the `registration` method.

Second commented line: Because `tx` is null. Which it will be if an exception occurs. For example in `getSessionFactory()`.

Limit your `try` statements. Here your exception clearly assumes that `session.save(c)` will fail, and that there is no other explanation. But that's clearly false: There are way more lines in that try block, and they could all be failing. If you are going to assume a particular line or error occured in a generalized exception block like this, the try block should contain *just* that.

In addition, when an exception occurs inside an exception handler, the exception that kicked it all off **is just gone**. So, you now can't tell which actual line got you to the exception handler. Fix that - for example by remarking out `tx.rollback()` temporarily to see what happens, and you know more. To fix this code properly, that try/catch should wrap `session.save(c); tx.commit()` and nothing else.

Also note that `tx.rollback()` can itself throw too.

In general this model of exception handling (catch it, take most of the info and toss it in the bin, print a stack trace to System.err which is not how you do logging, set a very generc 'failure' status, and then carry on as if nothing went wrong) is just broken. If an exception occurs, embrace it. Your `registration` method should be throwing something, not swallowing exceptions. In general if it does hibernate things, throwing SQLException is fine. Better than fine, you should be doing that.